# Office 365 Outlook Add-in. Anyway to find if user sending an email or calendar/meeting invite?

Tags: office-js

I'm creating an Office Add-In for Outlook that works with the calendar/meeting invite.

I'm working with the "onsend" that fires a function when a user hits the "send" button for either an email or a calendar/meeting invite.

My question is simple. Is there a way to see if the user is creating an email or a calendar/meeting invite.

If the user is creating an email, I just want to send the email. If a calendar/meeting invite, then my code would run.

Here is some code...it's very simple...

Manifest.xml part

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
     <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Here is the beginning code. I want to either check for if email or calendar/meeting invite in the validateBody. If it's an email, just send the email without running any code.

```
function validateBody(event) {

    mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
}

function checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack(asyncResult) {

    // Just send the email.
    asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemType` API to check for the current items type.
[Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.itemtype?view=outlook-js-preview)

```
function validateBody(event) {
    if (Office.context.mailbox.item.itemType == Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Message) {
        event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
    } else {
        mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
    }
}
```